# I cannot connect 2nd monitor Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I used to connect my 2nd screen but I cannot connect right now.I tried the monitor and cable in different laptop and it worked. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.`xrandar` is not detecting the second screen :

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
344mm x 194mm
1920x1080     60.03*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
1600x1024     60.17  
1400x1050     59.98  
1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
1280x1024     60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1400x900      59.96    59.88  
1280x960      60.00  
1440x810      60.00    59.97  
1368x768      59.88    59.85  
1360x768      59.80    59.96  
1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
1152x864      60.00  
1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
1024x768      60.04    60.00  
960x720       60.00  
928x696       60.05  
896x672       60.01  
1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
960x600       59.93    60.00  
960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
840x525       60.01    59.88  
864x486       59.92    59.57  
800x512       60.17  
700x525       59.98  
800x450       59.95    59.82  
640x512       60.02  
720x450       59.89  
700x450       59.96    59.88  
640x480       60.00    59.94  
720x405       59.51    58.99  
684x384       59.88    59.85  
680x384       59.80    59.96  
640x400       59.88    59.98  
576x432       60.06  
640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
512x384       60.00  
512x288       60.00    59.92  
480x270       59.63    59.82  
400x300       60.32    56.34  
432x243       59.92    59.57  
320x240       60.05  
360x202       59.51    59.13  
320x180       59.84    59.32
```

I tried to run `nvidia-smi` but I am getting the error *"NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."*
I checked `sudo prime-select query` and it says *nvidia*.

I also run the command `lspci | egrep -i "vga|display|3d"` , it shows following

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 
Mobile] (rev a1)
```

The last my driver version by running command `modinfo nvidia | grep version` is :

```
version:        495.46
```

The beggining of the day, I was training Darknet model, I thought GPU has been damaged. Has anyone encountered this problem? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you rebooted lately?  If the driver was updated, a reboot will be required.

Comment: Yes, I did. But it did not work as well. When I tried to run OpenCV, I got the error "GPU is not started".

Comment: It sounds like your gpu's driver is not correctly installed.